# Plotting from a table

Tags: plotting

I want to plot data from my table to look like this

[image]

```
f[k_, \[Alpha]_] := Assuming[0 < k < Pi,
  Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + \[Alpha]), {m, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify]
ListPlot[Table[FindArgMin[{4 f[k, \[Alpha]] (f[k, \[Alpha]] - A^2)/.A->1, 0 < k < Pi}, {k,1}],{\[Alpha],1,5}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[k_, α_] := 
 Assuming[0 < k < Pi, 
  Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify]

t = Table[{α, 
   First@FindArgMin[{4 f[k, α] (f[k, α] - A^2) /. 
       A -> 1, 0 < k < Pi}, {k, 1}]}, {α, 1, 10}]

ListLinePlot[t
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {α, Subscript[k, max]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Could please explain why what I was attempting was not working as I intended? I see you use ``ListLinePlot`` and this ``First@`` modifier. What do these do differently?

Comment: You have to pair $\alpha$ values with the calculated values and also remove the braces from the `FindMin`. Those are the two changes I made. If you remove the `First`, you will see what the output looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version similar to Syed nice solution.

I could not get the zero point added, too slow.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[k_?NumericQ, α_?NumericQ] := 
 Assuming[0 < k < Pi, 
  Simplify[Sum[(1 - Cos[k*m])/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, Infinity}]]]
data = Table[{α, 
   First@FindArgMin[{4 f[k, α] (f[k, α] - A^2) /. 
       A -> 1, 0 < k < Pi}, {k, 1}]}, {α, 1, 9}]
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 10}, {30, 0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

Comment: Thanks! The 0 point is slow because the sum is related to the riemann zeta function.

Could you please explain the difference in your solution? e.g, why write ``k_?NumericQ`` ?

Comment: I wrote my code before I saw there was an answer posted, but I figured might as well post it. I added `k_?NumericQ` since these arguments can only be numerical, because this is how you are calling it. It is not needed, but I like to add these to be safe. These are like adding types to arguments. Mathematica has  no type system, but this acts similar to that. Yes, zero was very slow so that is why I removed it.